# Camel RabbitMQ creates a generated queue in addition to the routing the msg to the queue

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have an exchange setup amq.topic and in there I have a routing key that is pointing to my key.

I have a route defined with a rest endpoint.  I make a call to that endpoint with a body as json {"sample" : "sample"}.

```
  rest("myendpoint")
                .post()
                .route()
                .routeId(ROUTE_ID)
                .log(ROUTE_ID + " started.")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .log("Receiving request with body=${body}")
                .to("rabbitmq://rabbiturl:port/amq.topic?connectionFactory=rabbitmqConnectionFactory&autoDelete=false&routingKey=myroutingkey&declare=false&exchangeType=topic")                
                .log(ROUTE_ID + " ended.")
                .end();
```

This accomplishes what I want to: the body of my rest call will be sent to the topic exchange of which will go to my queue based on the routing key.

The problem: It also create an auto-generated queue

```
 [                qtp86171426-28] RabbitMQProducer               INFO  Starting reply manager service RabbitMQReplyManagerTimeoutChecker[amq.topic]
[                qtp86171426-28] ReplyManagerSupport            INFO  Using temporary queue name: amq.gen-JGF0CKioQ6_MLA9uBNIOOQ
[                qtp86171426-28] CorrelationTimeoutMap          INFO  in putIfAbsent with key Camel-ID-L-VC-10050-58983-1467158153454-0-3
[nagerTimeoutChecker[amq.topic]] TemporaryQueueReplyHandler     INFO  in onTimeout with correlationId= Camel-ID-L-VC-10050-58983-1467158153454-0-3
[nagerTimeoutChecker[amq.topic]] ReplyManagerSupport            WARN  Timeout occurred after 20000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [Camel-ID-L-VC-10050-58983-1467158153454-0-3] on destination amq.gen-JGF0CKioQ6_MLA9uBNIOOQ. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: ID-L-VC-10050-58983-1467158153454-0-2 on ExchangeId: ID-L-VC-10050-58983-1467158153454-0-1) and continue routing.
```

I have tried skipqueuedeclare & skipexchangedeclare and am running out of ideas of why it is generating the queue.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set ExchangePattern to InOnly.

The temporary and reply queue is because the route expects a reply back so creates the temporary queue to wait for a response.

So if your rest endpoint does not return anything set the ExchangePattern to Inonly at the rest call and it should be ok. Alternatively set it at .to().

Comment: ya i ended up finding that out. i did .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly,  "rabbitmq://rabbiturl:port/amq.topic?connectionFactory=rabbitmqConnectionFactory&autoDelete=false&routingKey=myroutingkey&declare=false&exchangeType=topic")